# Calculating the kernel of a function $\phi: \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am kind of confused at the moment. The following function is given:

$$\phi: \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2}, \ A \rightarrow A + A^t$$

The task is to prove: $\ker{\phi} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}  \bigg \vert a = d = 0 \ \land \ b = -c  \right\}$

So what I did was the following:

Let $ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $\phi(A) = A+A^t = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}  + \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2a & b+c \\ b+c & 2d \end{pmatrix} $

Now for the kernel not being $0$, we must have $\det{\phi(A)} = 0$. Thus:

$$\det{\phi(A)} = 0$$
$$\det{\begin{pmatrix} 2a & b+c \\ b+c & 2d \end{pmatrix}} = 0$$
$$(b+c)^2 - 4ad = 0$$

Well okay... it is obvious that this is true for $a = d = 0 \ \land \ b = -c $ but it is also true for other other values, e.g. $a = 5 \land d = 0 \ \land \ b = -c $. That means that there are other values for which the kernel is not zero. So my first question is: Is that actually relevant for the nullspace? I does not imply that there are other solutions than $a = d = 0 \ \land \ b = -c$, does it?

The next thing I tried is just calculating the kernel which somehow confused me and therefore my second question: Since the parameter of $\phi$ is a matrix, do I still have to multiply the matrix with a vector? Maybe more accurately: Do I have to calculate this

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2a & b+c \\ b+c & 2d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = 0 \text{ or just } \begin{pmatrix} 2a & b+c \\ b+c & 2d \end{pmatrix} = 0$$

I would go for the second since the values you put into the matrix are $a,b,c,d$ - but I am not 100% sure that's why I am asking.

Now assuming my assumption is true I tried to calculate $\begin{pmatrix} 2a & b+c \\ b+c & 2d \end{pmatrix} = 0$. I d not use the Gaussian Algorithm but formed those equations:

$$\begin{array}{c} 2a + b + c = 0 \\ 2d + b + c = 0 \end{array}$$

Which again would be solvable using $a = d = 0 \ \land \ b = -c $ but also for other values. Now is the task only to verify that $a = d = 0 \ \land \ b = -c $ is a solution or is it means as $a = d = 0 \ \land \ b = -c $ being the only solution? If the latter, then I really won't know what to do.

Thank you very much for your help,
FunkyPeanut

Comment: $$A\in\ker\phi\iff A=-A^t$$ so
$a=-a$ and $d=-d$ and $b=-c$.

Comment: Well... that was easy... Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not being asked about the kernel of $A$ or the kernel of $\phi(A)$, but about the kernel of  $\phi$ itself, where $\mathbb Q^{2\times 2}$ is viewed as just a plain old 4-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$. The fact that elements of $\mathbb Q$ can themselves determine some linear transformations is irrelevant for the exercise.

The job is simply to determine the set
$$\{ A\in \mathbb Q^{2\times 2} \mid \phi(A)=0_{2\times 2} \}$$
that is, to find those $A$ such that $A+A^{\sf t}=0$.