# Image of $\phi: \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2}, \ A \rightarrow A + A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

This question is related to the question I previously asked:  [Kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740769/calculating-the-kernel-of-a-function-phi-mathbbq2-times-2-rightarrow).
The following function is given:

$$\phi: \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2}, \ A \rightarrow A + A^t$$

The task is to prove: $im{\phi} = \left\{ A \in \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2} | A = A^t  \right\}$.
I am stuck on this one again even though I feel that it is as easy as the last one was.
I know that for a linear function $f: V \rightarrow W$

$$im(f) = \{w \in W \ | \ \exists v \in V: f(v) = w\}$$.

So I said let $B \in \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2}$. Thus I have to check for whether there is an $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2}$ so that

$$\phi(A) = B \text{ ,right?}$$

But simply saying $A + A^t = B$ is not helping me at all...

Than you very much for your help once again.
FunkyPeanut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T = \{D \in Q^{2 \times 2} | D^t = D\}$

Let $B \in im(\phi)$. Then $B = A + A^t$ so $B^t = A^t + A = B$. So $im(\phi) \subset T$.

Let $A \in T$ so that $A^t = A$. Then write $A = \frac{A + A}{2}= \frac{A}{2} + \frac{A^t}{2}$. Note that $\frac{A}{2}$ is in $Q^{2 \times 2}$. So one can write $A = \phi(\frac{A}{2})$ therefore $A \in im\phi$ so $T\subset im(\phi)$.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer - and everything is clear except for one thing: What does $im(\phi) \subset T \subset im(\phi)$ exactly express? I don't see why this should be the solution for that... Thank you for your help.

Comment: For two sets $A$, $B$, $A \subset B \subset A$ expresses $A=B$. This is a common way to show two sets are equal when you can define them explicitly or implicitly. If you are asking why, the relations imply that neither $A$ contains an element which is not of $B$, nor $B$ contains an element that is not of $A$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! :)